# Unable to access Jenkins via HTTPS when using OpenJDK

Tags: jenkins, https, redhat-openjdk

I'm struggling to run Jenkins 2.91 (RPM version) using its embedded mode on Centos 7.2 with OpenJDK (1.8.0_65)

However I'm getting the "ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap" error when I connect with Firefox 38.1.0 over HTTPS

This problem does not occur when running Jenkins with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_144, only with OpenJDK.

I've tried various options such as the following without success

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

I came across [bug 1167153](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1167153), however the fix of applying `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=EC,ECDHE,ECDH` already appears to be in place in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/security/java.security`.

I've also tried using openssl to see what protocols are reported

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443
>>>
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA256
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA256
```

I enabled logging using `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` however this meant another fault was reported - ssl internal error - apparently due to bug -  [NoSuchAlgorithmException: EC AlgorithmParameters not available if SSL logs enabled](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=9482)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by installing bouncycastle. It seems OpenJDK doesn't ship with a ECC provider.

1. Download a bouncycastle provider from https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html. e.g [bcprov-ext-jdk15on-158.jar](https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-158.jar)
2. Copy into `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-<version>/jre/lib/ext`
3. Add a provider to the end of the list in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-<version>/jre/lib/security/java.security`

   `security.provider.9=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`
4. Re-enabled ECC algorithms, line previously ended: `, EC, ECDHE, ECDH`

   `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DH keySize < 768`
5. Restart jenkins